# Vuetifyjs: multiple v-text-field very slow response when keypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I used multiple `v-text-field` in Vuetifyjs, very slow response when keypress. Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqbBQy?&editable=true&editors=101):

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The codepen is working fine on MacOS. (This is supposed to be a comment, but for some reason, I cannot add a comment so had to post this as an answer).

Comment: You can get the issue when hold a key

Comment: Still works fine in Mac ^^' I guess it's either os-specific or browser-specific issue and not the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not OS related. It really depends on Browser and Computing power. If you open the same page in Chrome browser for example, the performance will be much better then in IE or Fire Fox. Also depends on which device you trying to render the page.

For instance, if you have several v-textarea on the same page, performance degrades considerably.

This is known issue and Vue team mentioned that they may fix it in Vue 3.

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6201